# Want to change the bar chart in matplotlib using slider

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change the number of bars as well as size of bars using slider. Slider works perfect if we just print the output of the slider values. But when I try to change the plot using those values console crashes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

// I have a function to generate two list bins and bins_count
// which I use to plot bar chart. 
// I am just writing the part in which I am having issue.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.3)

pl = plt.bar(bins, bins_count, align = 'edge')

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
mzlowerslide = plt.axes([0.25, 0.02, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=spcolor)
mzupperslide = plt.axes([0.25, 0.07, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=spcolor)
binslide = plt.axes([0.25, 0.12, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=spcolor)

low_mz = Slider(mzlowerslide, 'Lower Limit', 0, max(mass), valinit=lower_range)
high_mz = Slider(mzupperslide, 'Upper Limit', 0, max(mass), valinit=upper_range)
numbins = Slider(binslide, 'No. of Bins', 0, 100, valinit=binsize)

def update(val):
    lower = int(low_mz.val)
    upper = int(high_mz.val)
    binn = int(numbins.val)

    bins, bins_count = chart_values(mass, upper, lower, binn)


   pl.set_xdata(bins)
   pl.set_height(bins_count)
   fig.canvas.draw_idle()

low_mz.on_changed(update)
high_mz.on_changed(update)
numbins.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

**SOLUTION**

I added a subplot and clear that sub plot before ploting it again
Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
```

I have a function to generate two list bins and bins_count
which I use to plot bar chart. 
I am just writing the part in which I am having issue.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot (111)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.3)

ax.bar(bins, bins_count, align = 'edge')

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
mzlowerslide = plt.axes([0.25, 0.02, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=spcolor)
mzupperslide = plt.axes([0.25, 0.07, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=spcolor)
binslide = plt.axes([0.25, 0.12, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=spcolor)

low_mz = Slider(mzlowerslide, 'Lower Limit', 0, max(mass), valinit=lower_range)
high_mz = Slider(mzupperslide, 'Upper Limit', 0, max(mass), valinit=upper_range)
numbins = Slider(binslide, 'No. of Bins', 0, 100, valinit=binsize)

def update(val):
    lower = int(low_mz.val)
    upper = int(high_mz.val)
    binn = int(numbins.val)

    bins, bins_count = chart_values(mass, upper, lower, binn)

    ax.clear ()
    ax.bar (bins, bins_count, align = 'edge')
    fig.canvas.draw()

low_mz.on_changed(update)
high_mz.on_changed(update)
numbins.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If the number of bars changes, you need to create a new bar chart for them,  as you cannot update 4 bars with 8 bins.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeinfErnest I got it now